# How do I import cards from trello?

Tags: web-services, trello

I'm trying to make the functionality to let users "Import from Trello" like this:

https://support.meistertask.com/hc/en-us/articles/203039342-How-can-I-import-boards-from-Trello-

I can't find documentation on the Trello site about how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find documentation on the Trello site about how to do this.

Have you read the [api docs](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference)?